# Storing multiple lists of words permanently

Tags: android, database, save

This question might be a bit complex, but I´ll try anyway:

I am making an app which gathers a list of words in one language, and the translations of each word. Both in the same String array. I want the user to be able to store lists which he has made permanently, so they can be found later for practice. I have made a sketch underneath. It is very simplified.

In Activity1 the user chooses weather to make a new vocabulary list, or choose an old one (which then have had to be stored earlier). If the user makes a new list, he can choose to store it in Activity3. Between Activity2 and Activity3 there will be an Activity where the user practices translations of his vocabularylist. For simplicity, I have dropped this activity in the sketch.

How can I programatically make it possible to save vocabularylists that are made as String arrays from Activity3, and how can I give each list/array a name which the user can pick if he wants to choose an old list from Activity1?

I would be very thankful if someone could please guide me :-)

[image]

Comment: I would create a sqlitedatabase with the word as a primary key... 
Would this guide help?
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: I´l do my best! Thank you for your reply :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you putting all the words including translations in a single string array? Is it really required? Acc to the scenario, I don't think so..

Let's say the translation is required in only 1 language.

1. Make an SQLite table with three cols (id, word and word_trans)
2. In `Activity2` perform insert operation on each word.
3. In `Activity3` SELECT all the words, show them in a list and practice the translations. For a particular word translation,  UPDATE the sqlite-row and set word_trans value into that.
4. Now you have a table of user words, you can select it any time you want with the translation

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will try what you suggest.

Comment: How can I technically let the user of the app give a name to a specific list of words, and transfer this name as the name of the table? Like e.g let the user specify the name of a list in an EditText-field, and then make this variable-value the name of the table when creating a database-table: database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name_from_value_of_variable (foreignWord TEXT, translation TEXT)");

Comment: `String tableName = editText.getText().toString()` and then concatenate this string in your create table query. It's really a bad practice, never trust your users, never let them enter the table name.

Comment: How would the syntax be in the execSQL part? If not doing it this way, how can I technically let the app create new tables, and give them names without specifying them programatically when I make the app? (I´m sorry for my lack of knowledge, I´m just a hobbyprogrammer :-)